# duplicate row based if two fields cross years

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data structure:

```
df <- data.frame('unique_ref' = c("a_2016","a_2016","a_2016"),
                 'trans_type' = c('NB','MTA','MTA'),
                 'incept_dt' = c('01/07/2016','01/07/2016','01/07/2016'),
                 'exp_dt' = c('30/06/2017','30/06/2017','30/06/2017'),
                 'trans_dt' = c('01/07/2016','01/10/2016','01/02/2017'),
                 'trans_end_dt' = c('30/09/2016','31/01/2017','30/06/2017'))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_dt")), as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

> df
  unique_ref trans_type  incept_dt     exp_dt   trans_dt trans_end_dt
1     a_2016         NB 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2016-07-01   2016-09-30
2     a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2016-10-01   2017-01-31
3     a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2017-02-01   2017-06-30
```

Now what I want to do is check if trans_dt and trans_end_dt cross years, and if they do I want to update the trans_end_dt and trans_dt and duplicate the row. This is probably best explained through my dataset.

row 1: trans_dt and trans_end_dt are both in year 2016 so there is no problem

row 2: trans_dt is in year 2016 and trans_end_dt is in year 2017 so we have to do something here. I want the trans_end_dt to always be in the same year so I create a new row and replace the value of trans_end_dt in row 2

this will result in:

```
> df
  unique_ref trans_type  incept_dt     exp_dt   trans_dt trans_end_dt
1     a_2016         NB 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2016-07-01   2016-09-30
2     a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2016-10-01   2016-12-31
3     a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2017-01-01   2017-01-31
4     a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2017-02-01   2017-06-30
```

So what needs to happen is the trans_end_dt gets updated to the last day of 2016 then a new row is created which is the exact same as the prior row 2 but the only change is that it has the trans_dt as the start of 2017 and the same trans_end_dt as the prior row 2

the original row 3 has no movement in years between trans_dt and trans_end_dt so there is no issue and nothing will be done

My actual dataset has many "unique_refs" so this will need to be done in an automatic way if possible.

preferably dplyr solutions but will accept any as can't get my head around this!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility involving also `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(5:6), ~ as.Date(., format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 uncount((format(trans_dt, "%Y") != format(trans_end_dt, "%Y")) + 1) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 mutate(trans_end_dt = if_else(row_number() == 1 & n() != 1, 
                       as.Date(paste0(format(trans_dt, "%Y"),"-12-31")), 
                       trans_end_dt),
        trans_dt = if_else(row_number() == 2 & n() != 1, 
                           as.Date(paste0(format(trans_end_dt, "%Y"),"-01-01")), 
                           trans_dt)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rowid)

  unique_ref trans_type incept_dt  exp_dt     trans_dt   trans_end_dt
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <date>     <date>      
1 a_2016     NB         01/07/2016 30/06/2017 2016-07-01 2016-09-30  
2 a_2016     MTA        01/07/2016 30/06/2017 2016-10-01 2016-12-31  
3 a_2016     MTA        01/07/2016 30/06/2017 2017-01-01 2017-01-31  
4 a_2016     MTA        01/07/2016 30/06/2017 2017-02-01 2017-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses only base R but perhaps I think it is easier this way.

```
#Find the rows where the years are different for trans_dt and trans_end_dt
inds <- which(format(df$trans_dt, "%Y") != format(df$trans_end_dt, "%Y"))
#create a subset of those rows
subset_df <- df[inds, ]
#extract year from trans_end_dt and assign it to trans_dt
df$trans_dt[inds] <- as.Date(paste0(format(df$trans_end_dt[inds], "%Y"), "-01-01"))
#extract the year from trans_dt and assign it to trans_end_dt for subset_df
subset_df$trans_end_dt <- as.Date(paste0(format(subset_df$trans_dt, "%Y"),"-12-31"))
#rbind both the dataset to get duplicated row
rbind(df, subset_df)

#  unique_ref trans_type  incept_dt     exp_dt   trans_dt  trans_end_dt
#1      a_2016         NB 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2016-07-01   2016-09-30
#2      a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2017-01-01   2017-01-31
#3      a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2017-02-01   2017-06-30
#21     a_2016        MTA 2016-07-01 2017-06-30 2016-10-01   2016-12-31
```

Comment: I don't think this is working as you still have trans_dt and trans_end_dt which cross years. The trans_dt also needs to be updated for the new row

Comment: @user33484 ok..I had missed that. Updated now.